# How to manipulate a list of dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list of dataframes

```
mydata1<-data.frame(ID=1:3,age=c(15,20,32),sex=c("M","F","M"))
mydata2<-data.frame(ID=11:14,age=c(35,22,14,45),sex=c("F","F","M","M"),Diagnosis=c("Pneumony","AIDS","Cancer","Asthma"))
mydata3<-data.frame(ID=21:22,age=c(24,22),sex=c("M","F"),Country=c("France","UK"))

LST<-list(mydata1=mydata1,mydata2=mydata2,mydata3=mydata3)
```

and I want to select certain columns (ID and ages in this case) from each of the dataframe and then stack them by `rowbind()` in order to have such a dataset. I want to do all the manipulations on the list directly.

```
  ID age
1  1  15
2  2  20
3  3  32
4 11  35
5 12  22
6 13  14
7 14  45
8 21  24
9 22  22
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base R option -

```
cols <- c('ID', 'age')
do.call(rbind, lapply(LST, `[`, cols))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `map_dfr` from `purrr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)


LST %>% map_dfr(~.x %>% select(ID,age))

  ID age
1  1  15
2  2  20
3  3  32
4 11  35
5 12  22
6 13  14
7 14  45
8 21  24
9 22  22
```

`map_dfr` [directly binds rows](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html) for outputs of type `data.frame`.
The `~.x %>% select(ID,age)` notation is a shorthand for `function(df) df %>% select(ID,age)`